# Friendly_id name not displaying in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo, friendly-id

I have added the `friendly_id` gem to my application. The name attribute is not replacing the index in the URL.

**Gem**

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'
```

**Migration**

```
rails g migration add_slug_to_items slug:string
```

**Migration File**

```
class AddSlugToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :items, :slug, :string
    add_index :items, :slug
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  @searched_item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

**View-Path**

```
/views/items/show.html.erb
```

**Routes**

```
resources :items, only: [:new, :create, :update, :show]
```

**Button generating URL**

```
<%= link_to fr.name, item_path(fr.id, search_info: params), class:"searched_kennel_title_link default_green_color" %>
```

**Model**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    name_changed?
  end
```

**This is a pre-existing application so I also ran:**

```
 Item.find_each(&:save)
```

The strange part is that when the URL is generated it is originally: `http://localhost:3000/items/1`

When I manually change the URL to: `http://localhost:3000/items/item-name` it works.

Anyone have any idea why this would occur, or what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On you view: **Button generating URL**

```
<%= link_to fr.name, item_path(fr.id, search_info: params), class:"searched_kennel_title_link default_green_color" %>
```

Did you try to replace `item_path(fr.id, search_info: params)`

to: `item_path(fr, search_info: params)`

or: `item_path(fr.slug, search_info: params)`

Comment: Actually, deploying to heroku `fr.slug` was problematic. Simply using `fr` was the better choice resulting in no error on production.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
def show
  @searched_item = Item.find(params[:id])
end
```

You already have finders in your model.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but there was no change in the result, thanks though.

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 can you update your question with the view file where you're generating the url?

Comment: I cannot actually update with the content of the file as it is too large and belongs to a private client. `Items` is just a generic model being used. Is there something specific I should or shouldn't have in there?

Comment: @Ctpelnar1988 can you paste the line of code that generates the url instead of the whole view?